# Deployment of simple Spring web application on OSGI with Karaf

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, osgi, apache-karaf

I'm trying to run a simple Spring Web application on OSGI - Karaf 3.0.1 with no results.

On my fresh Karaf instance I've installed following features:

- spring 4.0.2.RELEASE_1
- spring-web 4.0.2.RELEASE_1
- pax-http 3.0.1
- pax-war 3.0.1
- war 3.0.1
- pax-jetty 8.1.14.v20131031

Here is my **[pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/75fDSDZ9)**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>co.chudy.kairos</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-web Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-osgi-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>spring-web</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <supportedProjectTypes>
                    <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                </supportedProjectTypes>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Vendor>Michal Chudy</Bundle-Vendor>
                    <Export-Package>co.chudy.kairos.spring</Export-Package>
                    <Web-ContextPath>kairos</Web-ContextPath>
                    <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>HelloWorldSpring</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean name="/helloWorld.do" class="co.chudy.kairos.spring.Home"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

And I've tried lots of things and searched a lot and still I'm getting stacktraces about missing context classes. I've tried different web.xml and servlet configurations and each time it was the same error - missing class. I also tried different versions of spring features.

Here is the stacktrace: ([full karaf log](http://pastebin.com/5W1CAhD1))

```
    2014-07-26 15:49:28,119 | INFO  | raf-3.0.1/deploy | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Updated D:\apache-karaf-3.0.1\deploy\spring-web.war
2014-07-26 15:49:28,439 | INFO  | raf-3.0.1/deploy | HttpServiceFactoryImpl           | 93 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 3.1.0 | Binding bundle: [spring-web [210]] to http service
2014-07-26 15:49:28,445 | INFO  | raf-3.0.1/deploy | fileinstall                      | 11 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.2.8 | Started bundle: file:/D:/apache-karaf-3.0.1/deploy/spring-web.war
2014-07-26 15:49:28,502 | INFO  | pool-13-thread-1 | AppHttpContext{spring-web - 210} | 84 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.14.v20131031 | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
2014-07-26 15:49:28,502 | INFO  | pool-13-thread-1 | DispatcherServlet                | 212 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc - 4.0.2.RELEASE_1 | FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
2014-07-26 15:49:28,503 | INFO  | pool-13-thread-1 | XmlWebApplicationContext         | 207 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context - 4.0.2.RELEASE_1 | Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Jul 26 15:49:28 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-07-26 15:49:28,504 | INFO  | pool-13-thread-1 | XmlBeanDefinitionReader          | 205 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans - 4.0.2.RELEASE_1 | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2014-07-26 15:49:28,526 | ERROR | pool-13-thread-1 | DispatcherServlet                | 212 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc - 4.0.2.RELEASE_1 | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver] for bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver not found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty [94]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:959)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:680)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)[207:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)[207:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)[79:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:222)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:197)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1032)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:422)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:341)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:678)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver not found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty [94]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1844)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:937)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)[85:org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:192)[85:org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:392)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    ... 47 more
2014-07-26 15:49:28,528 | WARN  | pool-13-thread-1 | AppHttpContext{spring-web - 210} | 84 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.14.v20131031 | unavailable
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver] for bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver not found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty [94]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:959)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:680)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)[207:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)[207:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)[212:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)[79:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:222)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:197)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1032)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:422)[93:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:341)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:678)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[136:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver not found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty [94]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1844)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:937)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)[85:org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:192)[85:org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_55]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:392)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:4.0.2.RELEASE_1]
    ... 47 more
```

But sometime the missing class was **OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext** or **ContextNamespaceHandler**.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Karaf, but if it's OSGi then you need valid OSGi bundles. I see you have in your pom the Maven bundle plugin but does it act on the Spring jars? As far as I know, everything Spring related after version 3.2.6 is not a valid OSGi bundle.

Comment: Maven bundle plugin does not include these files into war, since they are 'provided'. As my bundle is deployed on Felix, all dependencies are satisfied, so it should be OK. Spring jars are installed - they are provided by Karaf features. These are some descriptors collecting list of maven bundles to be installed to provide some functionality. As I understand, someone prepared bundles that embed spring packages and it's dependencies. Example: `org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web/4.0.2.RELEASE_1`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install Spring-DM also and use the OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext for it. 
A Sample can be found [here](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/war-spring-osgi).
In Short you'll need to switch to the following in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Today I realized that the piece I was missing was correct Import-Package statement. It seems that bundle plugin doesn't know about web.xml and therefore it does not put packages of classes like InternalResourceViewResolver into the manifest, so it should be done manually. (`*,org.springframework.web.servlet.view`)

Comment: So I managed to run Spring with `DispatcherServlet` configured. My question is: why do I need `OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext` for? Is it necessary for getting OSGI services? Can I use Declarative Services instead? I've read that Spring DM is not supported/developed anymore and that it's dependent on `Spring ~3`. Can I use it with Spring `4.0.2.RELEASE`, which I'm using now? Then.. would I have to keep two versions of Spring in OSGI?

Comment: It is right that spring-dm isn't developed any longer, AFAIK it still works in conjunction with Spring 3, Spring4 might not work.    
The `OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext` is needed for running with OSGi services. A mixture of Spring and DS, I doubt that it'll work, cause of the way the contexts are initialized. So who's in charge of doing the wiring? Which will take care of the injection of services, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok for your to confine your Spring WebMVC setup to one bundle and only use services from other bundles, you can have a look at [1]. There is a recipe [2] on how to use Eclipse Equinox (OSGi), EclipseLink (JPA) and Spring WebMVC with Jetty 9.2 and JSP/JSTL.

[1] http://dentrassi.de/2014/11/14/osgi-ee-modular-web-applications/

[2] https://github.com/ctron/osgiee/tree/master/web5